# finding highest number in Javascript from user input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have tried two different Javascript code to find the largest number from three user inputs. I am not getting the highest number from none of the codes. Please help!

HTML Code:

```
    Assignment 1: <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Assignment 2: <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    Assignment 2: <input type="text" name="num3"><br>

    <input type="button" id="high" value="high" onclick="high()">
    <input type="text" id="avg">

    <p id="result"></p>
```

JavaScript Code(Try 1):

```
function high() {
        let num1 = document.getElementsByName("num1")[0].value;
        let num2 = document.getElementsByName("num2")[0].value;
        let num3 = document.getElementsByName("num3")[0].value;

        var avg = Math.max(Number(num1),Number(num2),Number(num3))

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=avg;
```

JavaScript Code(Try 2):

```
function high() {
    let num1 = document.getElementsByName("num1")[0].value;
    let num2 = document.getElementsByName("num2")[0].value;
    let num3 = document.getElementsByName("num3")[0].value;

  if(Number(num1)>Number(num2) && Number(num1)>Number(num3))
    {
        document.getElementsByName("avg")[0].value = num1;
    }

   if(Number(num2)>Number(num1) && Number(num2)>Number(num3))
    {
        document.getElementsByName("avg")[0].value = num2;
    }

   if(Number(num3)>Number(num2) && Number(num3)>Number(num1))
    {
        document.getElementsByName("avg")[0].value = num3;
    }
```

Comment: Tried your first function and it worked, although you are writing `avg` every now and then, which is short for "average", not "highest".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the HTML from your answer and delete your answer. Answers should, well, answer the question.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question and explain what is not working about the attempts you have made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are making things complex try this code .

```
Assignment 1: <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
Assignment 2: <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
Assignment 2: <input type="text" name="num3"><br>

<button onclick="high()">Submit</button>

<p id="result"></p>

<script>

    function high(){
            var arr = document.querySelectorAll("input");
            var emptyarray = [];
            arr.forEach((elem) => {
                emptyarray.push(elem.value);
            })
            var max = Math.max.apply(null, emptyarray);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=max;
    }
</script>
```

you will get the heighest number result , you can restrict the input field to just enter the number so that no one can add string instead of number and your code work fine .

Comment: great :) if you this answer useful then you can mark this as answered so other people can see the answer as well .. thanks :)